# How are graphics produced on the screen?

Tags: graphics, computer-architecture, cpu-architecture

I have been trying to get a complete answer to this for a long time and I know it is complex.

For example lets say we wanted to produce the character 'H' on the screen. H is 72 in ascii or 48 in Hex and 00010010 in binary. Lets say that each side of H is 2 pixels wide and 10 pixels high and the middle line of H is 2x5 px.

We start with cout << "H";

The compiler then produces equivalent assembly code and the operating system/drivers load the program.

So what exact steps happen next. I have read some about registers, ALU units, Microcode.

Is a byte of memory set to 00010010. If so how does the CPU know how to take this byte and inform the GPU that it wants a set of pixels to be written to the screen at a certain area.

Is there some kind of lookup table hard coded into the electronics here or how does it work at the lowest levels.

Comment: If you want to write something to the screen you would communicate directly with the GPU normally through DirectX, OpenGL.  Your question shows a lack of research on the subject.

Comment: I know about GL and DX. Yes I can display on the screen using these graphics libraries, I want to know on a more fundamental basis both software and electronic.

Comment: Look into how GPU drivers work.  This question is slightly nonsense since the example code isn't even communicating with the GPU directly.